# How to tell which functions are evaluated at compilation time?

Tags: c++, clang

I'm developing a physics simulation program doing a lot of maths. I'd like to know exactly which functions (or code parts) are evaluated at compilation time.

It there a way to tell?
I'm using clang, usually with c++14.

Comment: Other than inspection of the generated code, there's no way to tell.

Comment: you will end up in creating a source code analyzer like ANTLR or other grammer based lexical tools, it is quite difficult to assume the #define macros etcc..,

Comment: `static` and `constexpr` expressions must be evaluated at compile time. Other than that, your compiler might choose to evaluate more things at compile time for optimizations sake. Like @JesperJuhl said, there is no way to tell other than inspecting the specific code.

Comment: @IradOhayon "constexpr expressions must be evaluated at compile time" - Not true. They *may* be evaluated at compile time, but they may also be evaluated at runtime.

Comment: @IradOhayon `constexpr` is *not* a requirement that something be evaluated at compile-time. It's merely a hint/request that "if this thing is used with constants, please evaluate it at compile-time" - but the compiler is well within its right to ignore that, and if you don't call the thing with constants it *has to* ignore you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language has precise rules about which expressions are evaluated at compile-time, and which are not. The technical term for that is *constant-evaluated*, and there is in fact a utility called [`std::is_constant_evaluated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated) that can be used to programmatically query whether a particular evaluation of an expression must happen at compile-time or not.

However, the language is still subject to the *as-if* rule, which allows the implementation to actually produce a program that evaluates expressions whenever it wants, *so long as* the program behaves *as-if* the expressions are evaluated when they are supposed to. In other words, `std::is_constant_evaluated()` is required to give the right results regardless.

In practice, an  implementation is allowed to produce a program that includes the entire compiler, and evaluates everything at run-time. Or the implementation can calculate all the results that it possibly can, even if it doesn't have to, and store them directly into the program it produces. Again, so long as the resulting program obeys the *as-if* rule, everything's ok.

If you want to know which expressions were *actually* evaluated at compile-time, you'll need to look at the assembly of the particular program generated by the implementation you're using.

Comment: `as if` + `In other words, std::is_constant_evaluated() is required to give the right results regardless.` isn't fully clear to me. Do I understand it right, that for `std::is_constant_evaluated(X)` the compiler is allowed to return `true` even if X wasn't actually precalculated during the compilation and is calculated on the fly at runtime, provided that it could had been precalculated but the compiler just decided not to?

Comment: [is_constant_evaluated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated) doesn't take an argument. The argument is actually the current evaluation context. And yes, the program is allowed to compute *everything* at run-time, so long as it pretends.

Comment: Right.. examples at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated are pretty clear, thanks. Especially the first one  :)